# Not able to use %26 or %amp for ampersand in url with multiple get requests

Tags: javascript

My url is as follows

```
        document.writeln("<form name='statistics' action='submit.php?p='+precision+'&amp;r='+recall+'&amp;a='+accuracy; onsubmit='return validateForm()' method='get'>")
        document.writeln("<button style = 'font-size: 32px; float : right'class = 'button' > See results </button>")
        document.writeln("</form>")
```

Where the url string is

```
'submit.php?p='+precision+'&amp;r='+recall+'&amp;a='+accuracy;
```

I have also tried

```
'submit.php?p='+precision+'%26r='+recall+'%26a='+accuracy;
```

However neither give me ampersands in the browser.

The url I get in my browser for both cases is as follows -

```
http://localhost/WT2ASST1/submit.php?p=1r=0.4a=0.4
```

I have not added any other relevant code with respect to the form submission and the url.

What do I need to do to get ampersands in my url?

Answer (score 0):

you're using the wrong string concatenation.
this should work:

```
document.writeln("<form name='statistics' action='submit.php?p="+precision+"&amp;r="+recall+"&amp;a="+accuracy+"' onsubmit='return validateForm()' method='get'>");
document.writeln("<button style = 'font-size: 32px; float : right'class = 'button' > See results </button>");
document.writeln("</form>");
```

note: if you want to concatenate strings you have to use the correct string delimiters e.g. "test"+var+"test"
not "test'+var+'test"

Answer (score 0):

This should give you ampersands (it did for me)

```
document.writeln("<form name='statistics' action='submit.php?p='+precision+'&amp;r='+recall+'&amp;a='+accuracy; onsubmit='return validateForm()' method='get'>")
```

But, the whole thing is in double quotes, so `+` will be a literal string instead of being an operator.  In the second case, you have an encoded URL.  Document.write won't magically decode those for you.  You could use the `decodeURI` function, but then it'd be the same if you'd just use the literal "&" to begin with.

Use your first method, but use double quotes to indicate where each string ends and where you want to concatenate a variable.  Like so

```
document.writeln("'submit.php?p='"+precision+"'&amp;r='"+recall+"'&amp;a='"+accuracy);
```

A quick note, you would only encode ampersands if you're not using them for their intended purpose of separating GET variables; which is how you're using them. Encoding those would likely just confuse the server.